# Hash password with salt in powershell (CBC, PKCS7, AES)

Tags: powershell, cryptojs

I'm trying to replicate the following JS-function into Powershell. It must match the exact same properties as I'm not able to change the other end where those values will be used.

```
// Function to encrypt values with Salt
function encryptMetadata(encryptStr, saltValue) {
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptStr.toString(), saltValue,
    {
        keySize: 256 / 8,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return encrypted.toString();
};
```

I tried to work with AesManaged and the following code, however, I'm failing to build the key.

```
 function Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {
    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256
    if ($IV) {
        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.IV = $IV
        }
    }
    if ($key) {
        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.Key = $key
        }
    }
    $aesManaged
}

function Encrypt-String($key, $unencryptedString) {
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($unencryptedString)
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject $key
    $encryptor = $aesManaged.CreateEncryptor()
    $encryptedData = $encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    [byte[]] $fullData = $aesManaged.IV + $encryptedData
    $aesManaged.Dispose()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fullData)
} 

 $hashedUsername = Encrypt-String $salt $inputUsername
```

Could anyone help me out on how to replicate this CryptoJS functionality in PS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters: in the JS you are using a keysize of 256 divided by 8 (so 32). In the PS version you are using a keysize of 256

Comment: Can you provide sample input/output values for the CryptoJS implemention for reference?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added an example on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6yo5h9px/1

However, now I'm even more confused. How can user-hashes be compared on the other end when by every execution the hash differs?

Comment: Example inputs:
```
encryptStr = "Not Set"
saltValue = "47007f54-fa54-467f-a767-abb22fe1336b"

Expected output: "U2FsdGVkX19uDoqJnp9iL0QgQ/nOZPhVbFvRcvdt2XA="
```
But I'm not getting that output with provided JS code, even tho its exactly whats being run.

Comment: The Powershell approach is looking for 32 characters in that salt whereas the dashes in the GUID result in 36 characters.  That's at least one of the issues.